# How to create a list inside a map where both contain pointers?

Tags: c++, std

I'm doing a project which requires

```
class course;
void add_student(map<int, map<int, list<course *> * > *> &DB, int id);
```

so when I check the course is not presenting, I want to create a list. Here is my code,

```
if(semesterIt == studentIt->second->end()){
DB[id][semester] = new list<course *>();
}
```

But when I run it, the compiler give me this error

```
no viable overloaded '='
```

No idea how to fix it. :(

Comment: What is the complete error?

Comment: `DB[id]` returns a pointer to a `map`, do you know if the pointer points to an actual `map` instance?

Comment: Try using `(*DB[id])[semester]` instead

Comment: You got your answer, but consider changing `map<int, map<int, list<course *> * > *>` to `map<int, map<int, list<course*>>>` to simplify your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB[id][semester] = new list<course *>();
```

is syntactically wrong since `DB[id]` evaluates to a pointer, not an object or a reference.

My suggestion:

```
auto& mapPtr = DB[id];
if ( mapPtr == nullptr )
{
  mapPtr = new map<int, list<course *> * >;

  // Not necessary since mapPtr is a reference to the element.
  // DB[id] = mapPtr;
}

auto& course_list_ptr = (*mapPtr)[semester];
if ( course_list_ptr == nullptr ) 
{
   course_list_ptr = new list<course*>;

   // Again, not necessary.
   // (*mapPtr)[semester] = course_list_ptr;
}
```

Comment: `auto & mapPtr` means you don't have to reassign `DB[id] = mapPtr;`, same with `auto & course_list_ptr`